# Is possible in Router Load Balance TP-Link TL-R470T+ use always same WAN (WAN3) for specific port

Tags: load-balancing, router

It is possible that all the traffic that pass through the port 25, goes by the same WAN interface?

My router is http://www.tp-link.us/products/details/?categoryid=&model=TL-R470T%2b

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible!
Just go to admin interface and Advanced -> Load Balance -> Policy Routing.
Create a policy with the destination port 25 and select the interface that you want the packets leave.